# Jasmine: How would I go about mocking an edited field in a model?

Tags: angular, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

in my services class I have several services. The main services are add, delete, and edit. I am having a little trouble figuring out how to mock the edit service. For add, I can easily see if the model is just passed or not, that is it. I am unsure how to mock an actual edit using jasmine that would actually edit the existing model and return the existing model. I do not want to create an initial model and set it equal to an edited model as that would not be testing my service. I figured I can use to toBe and compare a specific field that I change. I am honestly just unsure how I would change a field of my model within jasmne. I will share the structure of my test. I want to ensure that the edit service is actually working, not just me manipualting the model. I honestly may not have a grasp on unit tests, so if I am looking at this the wrong way, please let me now. Any advice would be great. Thank you!

Spec:

```
    fit('should edit the model',
inject([HttpTestingController, HttpService],
  (httpClient: HttpTestingController, service: HttpService) => {
    // We call the service


    service.edit(dummyPost, 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard').subscribe(body => {


    });
    // We set the expectations for the HttpClient mock
     const req = httpClient.expectOne({ url: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard', method: 'POST'});
      //expect(req.request.body).toBe(dummyPost); req.flush(dummyPost);
      expect(req.request.body.userId).toBe('EditedUserId');
```

service:

```
   edit(model, url: string): Observable<any[]> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.http.put(url, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}
```

Comment: Your service doesn't actually edit the model. It makes a request and returns data from the response, which is exactly what the testing module is designed for checking. See https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: Ahh that is what I figured. Thank you. So my test already takes care of that. Do you recommend I should test the functionality of the actual edit function in my component class? Or should my e2e test deal with that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could return a fake value :

```js
spyOn(service, 'edit').and.returnValue(Observable.of(/* your new value */));
```

But that would render your test useless. This would be like trying this :

```
const str = 'xxx';
expect(str).toEqual('xxx');
```

Comment: Yeah :/. That is what I was thinking about before posting here. I am unsure if I should even unit test this sort of functionality. I have an e2e test that checks if the UI changed, and a unit test that checks if PUT is called.

Comment: You're right on that. What I do is basically the same : I test if the right endpoint is called with the right verb, and I check that the updated value is returned. But I don't check if the value matches something like you did there. This is done with e2e testing, like you said.